# how to submit form with ajax and php to avoid page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form on page in php,But i don't want the page to refresh,I go through many tutorials,But still can't figure it out someone should me fix my code please.

index.php

```
<script src="profile.js"><script>
  <div class="sta">
    <form action="test.php" method="POST" id="sta">
      <input type="text" name = "sta" id="sta" placeholder="Status">
      <input id="submit" onclick="status()" type="button" value="save">
    </form>
  </div>
</script>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'db.php';

  if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $eml = $_SESSION['email'];

    $sql = $con->prepare("update alert_users_account SET statu=? where email_phone=?");
    $sql->bind_param('ss',$_POST['sta'],$eml);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->close();
  }
?>
```

profile.js

```
function status() {
  var sta = document.getElementById("sta").value;

  var dataString = 'sta1=' + sta;
  if (sta == '') {
    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
  } else {
    // AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: where are you using `sta1`? - Look at your developer console, use php's error reporting and check for errors on the query, if any.

Comment: use event.preventDefault() onclick of submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the return with `onclick="return status()"`

```
<input id="submit" onclick="return status()" type="button" value="save">
```

**or** try with in `form.submit`

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return status()" id="sta">
  <input type="text" name="sta" id="sta" placeholder="Status">
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="save">
</form>
```